# Surface integral where $S$ is the surface of a solid bounded by cylinder $x^2+z^2=4$ and planes $y=0$ and $y=3$.

Tags: integration, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

$$\iint_{S}\langle-3z^2,1-x,(y-2z)\rangle\,d\vec{s}$$
I am trying to solve this surface integral where $S$ is the surface of a solid bounded by cylinder $x^2+z^2=4$ and planes $y=0$ and $y=3$, I arrived with the Divergence theorem and cylindric coordinates in
$$\int_{0 }^{2\pi}\int_{3 }^{0}\int_{-\sqrt{4-^2\cos^2\Theta}  }^{\sqrt{4-^2\cos^2\Theta} }\,dz\,dr\,d\Theta, $$ but it doesn't have a solution, maybe mt limits are wrong?[image]

Comment: Modify cylindrical coordinates to take advantage of the geometry here. The axis of the cylinder is the $y$-axis, not the $z$-axis. Moreover, you should know the volume of a cylinder without doing any integrals.

Comment: So just change the order of integration?

Comment: No. Didn't my remark say specifically to *modify* cylindrical coordinates? If the $y$-axis is the axis of the cylinder instead of $z$, then you should use $y$ as the non-polar variable and write $x$ and $z$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: So $\int _0^{2\pi }\int _0^2\int _0^3\:\left(y-2\right)dydrd\theta $? with y=y x=rcos(θ) and y=rsin(θ)

Comment: Yes, although I don't know where your $y-2$ came from. It should be just $-2$. You are also missing the $r$ from $r\,dr\,d\theta$. You were missing this above, too. Review integrals in polar coordinates.

Comment: The y-2 is because the div F

Comment: What do you mean by $-\sqrt{4-^2\cos^2\Theta}$?

Comment: Instead of the usual $x=r \cos \theta, y=r \sin \theta$, try $x=r\cos \theta, z=r\sin\theta$ to get a cylindrical coordinate system in $y, r, \theta$.

Comment: @aschepler You’ll note that i suggested this some hours ago.